# Зачем писать аннотацию @Column если она ни на что не влияет

Tags: java, spring

Видимо, я не понимаю смысл.

Есть сущность, у этой сущности есть колонки в базе данных, и есть простое поле, не помеченное аннотацией @Column, но при вставке данных через JSON Spring мне самостоятельно из простого поля private int tokenCount добавил новую колонку в базу данных и сам записал туда значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно и сам вопрос, я не так понимаю эту аннотацию @Column? Зачем, в таком случае, вообще писать?

Comment: Простите, не могу найти, как пометить поле у сущности, чтобы по нему не создавалась строка в таблице в БД?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Я случайно увидел ваш комментарий, в следующий раз пишите комментарии в том вопросе или ответе, где его контекст =)

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через аннотацию `@Column` можно явно указать поведение столбца. Если откроете ее реализацию, то увидите, что столбцу можно задавать такие свойства, как уникальность, обновляемость и т.д.

Во всех остальных случаях, все поля в классе, помеченном как `@Entity`, неявно станут столбцами этой таблицы.

Чтобы по некоторым объявленным полям не создавались столбцы в БД, поставьте над ними аннотацию `@Transient`.